# node-steam-group-chat problems, weird var

Tags: javascript, node.js

So I am attempting to decipher this guy's code at [node-steam-group-chat github.](https://github.com/bonnici/node-steam-group-chat) So that I can locally host (or on a webserver) a mobile group chat client to play D&D with my friends using steam group chat. The only thing is (and yes, I have asked people who have even used the authors code for the trash bot and they did not know what the heck he is talking about.) that I don't know what some of the process.env s are. (See below)

```js
exports.init = function() {
    process.env.PORT = 8001;
    process.env.SteamChatProxyUserId = 'xxx';
    process.env.SteamChatProxyUserName = 'xxx';
    process.env.SteamChatProxyUserPassword = 'xxx';
    process.env.SteamGroupId = 'xxx';
    process.env.ExpressCookieSecret = 'xxx';
    process.env.ExpressSessionKey = 'xxx';
    process.env.SteamWebApiKey = 'xxx';
    process.env.SocketIoChatRoom = 'xxx';
    process.env.SteamOpenIdVerifyUrl = 'http://localhost:8001/steamverify';
    process.env.MongoUrl = 'xxx';
}
```

Things like the WebAPI key, username, password, groupid, and id are all fine; just the MongoURL, SteamOpenIdVerifyUrl, SocketIoChatRoom, ExpressSessionKey, all don't make sense.
If I knew how to get some of the env from above, I would be able to fill it out by myself.

Answer (score 1):

This program is designed to run on Heroku; that's what the Procfile is there for. Heroku uses environment variables to store information, rather than having you add information to a config file, and allows you to modify environment variables through their tool. Among other advantages, this way you can run your code straight from a development server. You can also set up a 'Heroku Button' that allows other users to create an instance of your project just by filling out a form that sets the variables for them.

MongoDB is a database. The MongoUrl is probably a hostname/ip:port string for storing the messages.

If you still need information on the other variables, you can try asking Bonnici yourself. I see [you never made an issue](https://github.com/bonnici/node-steam-group-chat/issues), so maybe you can [try that](https://github.com/bonnici/node-steam-group-chat/issues/new); the developer is more likely to know that anyone else.